# Interface method argument types ignored by TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Surprisingly to me, the following code compiles with no errors (tsc 3.9.5):

```
interface IDateHandler {
  handleDate: (Date) => void;
}

let dateHandler: IDateHandler = {
  handleDate: (d: Date) => {},
};

dateHandler.handleDate([1, 2, 3]);
```

Even more surprisingly, if `handleDate([1, 2, 3])` is replaced with `handleDate([1, 2, 3], 4)`, `tsc` emits `error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.`

So it's clearly aware of `handleDate`'s function signature, but for some reason it's completely ignoring the types themselves.

Even **more** surprisingly, omitting the interface declaration makes type checking work as expected:

```
let dateHandler = {
  handleDate: (d: Date) => {},
};

dateHandler.handleDate([1, 2, 3]);

// error TS2345: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'.
//   Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Date': toDateString, toTimeString, toLocaleDateString, toLocaleTimeString, and 37 more.
```

What gives?

Comment: [There is a compilation error in 3.9.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE6QBJxAEwBtpkBvAWAChlkALPIiTSALmQApmIBKZAXgB8yAG4B7YPgDcVAL5UqxMMnxYIuAsShsMq9Yyj8yVGvQ1NVbdvjZdegsjIA0s6ZSoqcDTQDpTjLuwA2gCMjsgATGEAzAC63JJAA) and [the nightly build](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-dev.20200621#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE6QBJxAEwBtpkBvAWAChlkALPIiTSALmQApmIBKZAXgB8yAG4B7YPgDcVAL5UqxMMnxYIuAsShsMq9Yyj8yVGvQ1NVbdvjZdegsjIA0s6ZSoqcDTQDpTjLuwA2gCMjsgATGEAzAC63K5AA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that the code is likely broken on line 2. There should be a param type specified in the handleDate signature.

The reason it compiles is that the code itself is kind of valid. In your code, you have a param with name `Date` and **with no type** specified.

What you should do is to add a `--strict` or `--noImplicitAny` compiler options to your tsc config (either tsconfig.json or command line params). Once done you should get an error like

```
Error:(2, 18) TS7051: Parameter has a name but no type. Did you mean 'arg0: Date'?
```

See:
[Typescript Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem myself after checking @VLAZ's comment:

When TypeScript's default "implicit any" behavior is enabled, `(Date) => void` becomes `(Date: any) => void`.

Changing the function type signature to `(d: Date) => void` makes `tsc` report the expected: `error TS2345: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'.`